# Defining y-starting point for floating horizontal bar charts in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I've created a horizontal bar graph with a logarithmic x-axis:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [1000000000, 100000000, 10000000, 1000000, 100000, 1000],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
                                xAxes: [{
                        type: 'logarithmic',
                        position: 'bottom',
                        ticks: {
                            userCallback: function(tick) {
                                var remain = tick / (Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Chart.helpers.log10(tick))));
                                if (remain === 1 || remain === 5) {
                                    var test = tick.toString();
                                        if(test >= 1000 && test < 1000000){
                                            return tick/1000 + "kHz";
                                        }else if(test >= 1000000 && test < 1000000000){
                                            return tick/1000000 + "MHz";
                                        }else if(test >= 1000000000){
                                            return tick/1000000000 + "GHz";
                                        }else {
                                            return tick.toString() + "Hz";
                                        }



                                }
                                return '';
                            },
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            labelString: 'Frequency',
                            display: true,
                        }
                    }]
                }
    }
});
```

But I can't seem to be able to define the starting point, all the bar graphs originate at y-0.

I was wondering if it was possible at all with Charts.js, and if so, how, because I can't seem to be able to find anything about it in their documentation or at their git, Googling hasn't helped either.

[Here is what I have right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULQ8z.png)

[Here is what I would like to have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2mzw.png)

Comment: I can't seem to find a possible solution for you since the data that a bar chart takes is only arrays. If that allowed for a starting point value, then maybe, but doesn't seem to be the case. Multi axes bar charts might help you.

Comment: I found a workaround that seems to be easier, but thanks for the suggestion, multi-axis would've worked too.

Comment: I did see the stacked charts option, but I wasnt sure you could give each bar a different colour then. Which was why I suggested the multi axes option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way as of now seems to be stacking the bar chart with invisible charts as the padding on the x-axis (as suggested [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2912)), it works pretty well.

There is possibly a multi-axis solution as well, as suggested by [@Arathi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3688348/arathi-sreekumar) in the comments.